# Rack app: can't activate rack, already activated

Tags: ruby, rubygems, passenger, rack, dreamhost

I have a Sinatra Rack app running on Dreamhost.

Currently I'm croning the app every 15 minutes and logging its output. 90% of the time the app loads just fine, but about 10% of the time I get the following error: http://jsfiddle.net/dBrUa/embedded/result/

**can't activate rack (~> 1.3, >= 1.3.6, runtime) for ["sinatra-1.3.2"], already activated rack-1.2.1 for []**

What should be the cause of this? And why does it happen unexpectedly?

Answer (score 4):

You have two different version of Rack, if you uninstall older version then it may work fine.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall rack
```

It will show you all installed rack version and if you find there are two or more version of Rack present then uninstall all except rack >= 1.3.6